# Naive Bayes Classification: Understanding example correctly?

Tags: algorithm, information-retrieval, text-classification, naivebayes, multinomial

I am currently looking into the multinomial model for Naive Bayes classification, and have come across the following example:

[image]
[image]

I think I understand everything, but I have developed the following reasoning I would like confirmed:

For a given class c, and document d consisting of terms t1, t2, ..., tn. Here is how to calculate P(c|d):

- P(class | doc): (prior[c]) * (prob[t1 in c]) * (prob[t2 in c]) * ... * (prob[tn in c])
- P (! class | doc): (prior[!c]) * (prob[t1 in !c]) * (prob[t2 in !c]) * ... * (prob[tn in !c])

Is this correct? And thus, is this the reason the power 3 is present in both (3/7) and (2/9), denoting P(Chinese|c) and P(Chinese|!c) together with the fact that 'Chinese' appears three times in d5?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you should probably ask this on stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: Your understanding is correct. (how you calcuate p(c|d) and why you need the power of 3). :)